# Docker memory limit is exceeded

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file:

```yml
version: "2.4"
services:
  auto_check:
    image: python
    mem_limit: 97M
```

That upon startup runs the following python script:

```py
x = 'a' * (2 * 10 ** 8)
```

As expected, the docker fails with error code 137.
However, when I set `mem_limit: 98M`, **the error does not reproduce**.
Any idea why docker allows such an extreme memory limit violation?
The image size is 135MB (ubuntu20+python3).

(Running on WSL2-ubuntu:20.04)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: On my machine 98M still gives code 137 but 99M+ doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `memswap_limit` defaults to the value of `mem_limit`, meaning you get `mem_limit` regular memory and another `memswap_limit ( == mem_limit)` of swap memory, for a total of 2x `mem_limit`.

You can either set `mem_limit` to be half as much as your actual required limit, or alternatively you can set `memswap_limit: 0M` to disable swap altogether.

Running

```
/usr/bin/time --verbose python3 -c "x = 'a' * (2 * 10 ** 8)" 2>&1 1>/dev/null | grep 'Maximum resident'
```

on my machine we can see that

```
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 203708
```

memory is used by this Python script at its peak. In MiB terms that's `203708000 / 1024 / 1024 ~ 194MiB`. Half of that is ~`97MiB`. That's where the 98-99M limit you observed comes from. ~98MiB for regular memory, ~98MiB for swap, a total of ~194MiB, which is ~the peak memory consumption of `python3 -c "x = 'a' * (2 * 10 ** 8)"`